# adding modulus to rand() in c++ affects execution outside a for loop, why and how to remedy?

Tags: c++

I am a c++ beginner and I hope you could help me with some of the fun I am having, you all know what I actually mean.

Here is a snippet of c++ code that I will follow with a brief explanation my problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime> 
#include <cstdlib> 
using namespace std;

int main() {
// this first for loop doesn't affect the execution of the first cout statement.

for (int i = 51; i >= 0; i--) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int j = rand(); 
    cout << j << endl;
};

cout << "first cout outside the first for loop" << endl; // executes fine

// this second for loop affects the execution of the following cout statement.

for (int i = 51; i >= 0; i--) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int j = rand() % i; //by just adding % i, the next cout statement doesn't execute!
    cout << j << endl;
};

cout << "second cout outside the second for loop" << endl; // doesn't execute
}
```

All right, so, I hope the issue is obvious. To put it in words, why adding the modulus i to the rand() in the second for loop prevents the second cout statement from execution? It took me a whole lot of time to pinpoint what seems to be a big problem in my entire class implementation to this single line. Any feedback/advise/explanation is greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Call srand once, at the start of your program.

Comment: `rand() % 0` is UB.

Comment: Thanks Neil, this is a great advise, yet, the issue of the second cout statement not executing is still obtaining!

Comment: `endl` should be flushing, but possible your `cout` statements are backed up and waiting to print when the program crashes over the aforementioned `rand() % 0;` Step through the program with the debugger that came with your development environment and see what happens.

Comment: I got it now, the issue came with taking modulus over a zero, my bad. Thanks folks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programs that execute undefined behavior can have any apparent behavior, including code "in the past" not executing.

You do `%0` at the end of your loop.  This makes earlier print statements not output.  That is acceptable behavior as far as C++ is concerned.

Don't do undefined behavior.

Comment: I got it now, the issue came with taking modulus over a zero, my bad. Thanks Yakk.